# Can we use vectors in C++ library being called from a C# program?

Tags: c#, c++, bad-alloc

I have a C# application that uses C++ library. In one of the functions of the library, I'm constructing a vector of objects of a class. however, when I use `push_back()` to add the objects to the vector I'm getting a `bad_alloc` error. Can anyone please explain why this might be happening?

part of my code is as follows:

```
vector< EVector > CalibrationHelper::calcCalibrationPoints( ..... )
                                           {
std::vector< EVector > vertices;

if(h > 1 && v > 1)
{
    ....
    if (h >= 2 && v >= 2)
    {
       for (int x = 0; x < h; x++)
       {
           for (int y = 0; y < v; y++)
           {
               EVector p;

               p.x = x * ( bW + marginX ) + marginXLeft;
               p.y = y * ( bH + marginY ) + marginy;

               p.x += shiftX;
               p.y += shiftY;
                try{
               vertices.push_back(p);
               }catch(std::bad_alloc& ba){
                   std::cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
               }

           }
       }
    }
}

return vertices;
}
```

after the first `push_back()` the size of the vector `vertices` is changing to an unusually large number when it should increase by one.

Comment: You should provide C# part of sample too... Also since there is no binary standard on memory layout of `std::` types chances to get such code working correctly in somewhat reliable manner are quite low.

Comment: This function is not being called from the C#. It's being used by the library only.

Comment: Check what is happening inside the constructor of EVector, since it will be invoked on each push_back(p) call.

Comment: I assumed the default copy constructor should be called. When I defined my own copy constructor it wasn't getting called either. It is picking default values.